# Check if a video file has subtitles

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, ffmpeg

Is it possible to check if a video file has a subtitle using bash and get a simple answer like "yes" or "no". I don't need to know any details about the subtitles.

Maybe using ffmpeg?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should display a `0` if subtitles are found, and `1` if not found.

```
ffmpeg -i video -c copy -map 0:s:0 -frames:s 1 -f null - -v 0 -hide_banner; echo $?
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I am trying to accomplish!

Comment: Works perfectly also to check if a file has an audio or video stream by replacing "-map 0:s" with "-map 0:v" for video for example.

Comment: The negative check fooled me. To display "1" with subtitles and "0" without try:

ffmpeg -i video -c copy -map 0:s -f null - -v 0 -hide_banner && echo "1" || echo "0"

Comment: This doesn't work here anymore and gives always an empty `ffmpeg` output. Version 4.4 here. What works is `mediainfo --Inform="General;%TextCount%" videofile` which outputs true for no subtitles and if they exist, the number of subtitles.

Comment: Works here. You may have an empty sub stream. Let me adjust the command.

Comment: could you explain the arguments , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Bash

```sh
ffmpeg -i $filename 2>&1 | grep "Subtitle:"
```

Powershell

```
ffmpeg -i $filename 2>&1 | select-string "Subtitle:"
```

Explanation:
The `ffmpeg` command fails if no output file is provided, but the error message contains all information about the input file. The expression `2>&1` redirects error stream to standard output so it can be piped into `grep`/`select-string` command.